Etherscan shows token balance in my wallet but the value is 0
I would appreciate your help. Etherscan shows balance in my wallet for a token Agix (AGX), but the value is 0. I might have been scammed, but I am not sure. Could you please help me verify this. This is the transaction hash: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8d83d3f36b1deec3be8ecd5adc019053790fc819c55334bb103bcadda8186ce8 and the balance of AGX shown in my wallet is 76,086.456765815, but as a matter of fact I've got 0. Please explain what happened. Thank you.

I can see the tokens in your wallet. But I think etherscan is unable to show its price.
You have the tokens though.

